# How to verify that input field has changed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, alert, onchange

The method I wrote checks if the date has inserted/changed in input field, and I want to trig confirm message to the user when this condition is true. 
The problem that the confirm message is triggered every time even when the date has not changed. My method looks like below:

```
   var alertuserSave = function() {
        val4 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").val();
         var alrt_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
         alrt_value.type = "hidden";
         alrt_value.name = "confirm_value";
         if ((val3 === "5" || val3 === "6") && val4) {
         confirm("Remember to Save the inserted data.");
         alrt_value.value = "Yes";
         } else {
             alrt_value.value = "No";
         }


         document.forms[0].appendChild(alrt_value);
     }
```

And I added a listener on document load like this:

```
var val3 = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlResponsibility').val();
    var val4 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").val();
    console.log(val4 + " is val4 ")
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").change(alertuserSave);
```

How to make the pop up fired only when the date has changed and not every time?

Comment: What should '&& val4' do?

Comment: You can use focus and blur events on your date field.You can store the date's value on focus and then In your blur function you can check if the final & initial strings are same or not and fire your function if the date are different :)

Comment: @JonasSchafft I suppos to check that val4 value han't changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
val4 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").val();
```

**returns the value** of the element

so if you check:

```
(...  && val4)
```

it is always true

you need to check something like:

```
val4 != oldvalue
```

Comment: And how to get the oldvalue? I tried to save the old value via var val4 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").data('val4', $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").val());  but this does not work it prints out the current value always

Comment: Just do val4 != $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").val() and then do the val4 = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized").val(); after the check.